# updating dataframe on the basis on text in one column

Tags: r

I want to transform the data frame on the basis on column house. so if the columns house have text seprated by ";" the add the text in new row. and also add the new column with head1, head2

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-  data.frame(Region = c("AU","USA","CA","UK","GE","AU","USA","CA","UK"),
                  lock = c(1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA),
                  type= c("sale",NA,NA,"target","target",NA,"sale",NA,"target"),
                  House =c("Tagore house","Gandhi house",NA,"Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house","Tagore house",NA,"Flexible;Gandhi house","Gandhi house","Gandhi house"))

df %>%
  mutate(House = strsplit(House, ";"),
         head= head) %>%
  unnest(House)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(House, sep = ";") %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   mutate(Head = if(n() > 1) c(str_c("head", seq_len(n()-1)), "") else "", 
 across(c(Region, lock, type), ~ replace(.x, row_number() != n(), ""))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   Region lock  type     House        Head   
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <chr>  
 1 "AU"   "1"   "sale"   Tagore house ""     
 2 "USA"  "1"    <NA>    Gandhi house ""     
 3 "CA"   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>         ""     
 4 ""     ""    ""       Flexible     "head1"
 5 ""     ""    ""       Tagore house "head2"
 6 "UK"   "1"   "target" Gandhi house ""     
 7 "GE"   <NA>  "target" Tagore house ""     
 8 "AU"   "1"    <NA>    <NA>         ""     
 9 ""     ""    ""       Flexible     "head1"
10 "USA"  <NA>  "sale"   Gandhi house ""     
11 "CA"   "1"    <NA>    Gandhi house ""     
12 "UK"   <NA>  "target" Gandhi house ""
```

Comment: but i dont want to update region,lock, type column, want to keep them blank